# Is it possible to set variable as part of other variable's name

Tags: php, variables, variable-names

I have summarized data of many kinds of fruits like apple, melon, orange, pear, grape,... etc.
My code below works ok, but I like to make it template if possible.

```
<?php $fruit_name='apple' ?>
<?php include("args.php")?> // Using $fruit_name as condition of $args, and $number is caculated then.
<?php $number_apple_fruit = $number;?> // Store $number to $num_apple_fruit to distinguish data from other fruit data.
```

Im wondering if I can set "apple" on position of AAAAA below automatically on third line.

```
<?php $fruit_name='apple' ?>
<?php include("args.php")?>
<?php $number_AAAAA_fruit = $number;?>
```

Is it possible to set variable to part of other variable's name?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: You could also use an array to store different numbers for different fruit

Comment: It would be apprecited if you can show how to make it by array method.

Comment: Just a standard associative array? `$fruit = [ "apple" => 1, "orange" => 2];` or similar. Then `echo $fruit["apple"];` to show the associated number. Or as per your example, `$fruit_name='apple'; echo $fruit[$fruit_name];`

Comment: Thank you for your kindly example.  Variable variables works fine in my case, but I will try array method too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```php
${'number_'.$fruit_name.'_fruit'} = $number;
```

Comment: Thank you !  your variable variables method works completely !

Comment: @cwhiro variable variables are an antipattern. Use arrays instead.

Comment: @miken32 I don't want to be rude, but saying something is "antipattern" is not logical reasoning, but rather a religious belief. Especially when not backed up by research or any sources. My personal belief is that PHP at its heart is still a scripting language - and should have dangerous features like this that enable really high abstraction - and often quick results.